# Tengo este problema para desarrollar y los intentos que hago han fallado, es sobre buscar una letra en una lista en python, abajo les explico

Tags: python, lista

**Realizar un programa que agregue n palabras y en una nueva lista agregar solos las  palabras que comienzan con la letra solicitada después de ingresar la lista de  palabras.**

Hasta ahora el progreso que he escrito es esto:

```
print("""
    1) Añadir palabra                   
    2) Buscar por letra solicitada  
    """)

Palabras=[]
solo=[]
numpal=(int(input("Cuantas palabras añadira: ")))

A= Palabras=[]  
for A in range (numpal):
    A= Palabras.append(str(input("Nueva palabra: ")))
   

opcion=input("Escoja su opcion:")
if opcion=="1":
   A= Palabras.append(str(input("Nueva palabra: ")))
   Palabras.sort()
   print(Palabras)
   
elif opcion=="2":
    x=(input("Que letra busca: "))
    index = Palabras.find(x)
    aux[index] = x
```

**Ya añane el n numero de palabras a una lista**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero este programa no tiene nada que ver con tu ejercicio....

Comment: Como que no tiene nada que ver con mi ejercicio bro?

Comment: Claro. La primera parte ok. La segunda tu programa dice que busca palabras... pero no hace nada parecido a eso.. lo que dice tu ejercicio es que tenes que pasar a otra lista las palabras que comienzen con la letra que esscribiste...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Datos():
    continuar = True
    palabras = []
    palabrasLetra = []

def main():

    def acciones():
        opcionEscogida = -1
        while type(opcionEscogida) != int or opcionEscogida not in (1, 2, 3):
            try:
                opcionEscogida = int(input("Introduzca 1, 2 o 3 para seleccionar una opción: "))
            except:
                pass

        if opcionEscogida == 1:
            palabraIntroducida = None
            while type(palabraIntroducida) != str:
                try:
                    palabraIntroducida = input("Introduzca una palabra: ")
                    Datos.palabras.append(palabraIntroducida)
                except:
                    pass

        if opcionEscogida == 2:
            letraSolicitada = None
            Datos.palabrasLetra = []
            while type(letraSolicitada) != str:
                try:
                    letraSolicitada = input("Introduzca una letra para buscar: ")
                except:
                    pass
            for i in range(len(Datos.palabras)):
                if Datos.palabras[i][0] == letraSolicitada:
                    Datos.palabrasLetra.append(Datos.palabras[i])
            print("Las palabras que empiezan por", letraSolicitada, "son: ")
            for i in range(len(Datos.palabrasLetra)):
                print(Datos.palabrasLetra[i])

        if opcionEscogida == 3:
            Datos.continuar = False

    while Datos.continuar:
        print()
        print("1) Añadir palabra")
        print("2) Buscar por letra solicitada")
        print("3) Salir del programa")
        print()
        acciones()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Se pide al usuario que introduzca 1, 2 o 3 para seleccionar una opción del menú.

Si introduce 1, entonces se le pide que introduzca una palabra, y esta es añadida a la lista `palabras`.

Si introduce 2, las palabras que empiecen por la letra introducida son añadidas a la lista `palabrasLetra`. Posteriormente, se recorre la lista y se muestra al usuario.

Si introduce 3, el programa termina su ejecución.